# How to integrate VSCode with the Visual C++ compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-code

How to integrate Visual Studio Code with the Visual C++ compiler to build and debug C++ MFC solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to try and use on e of the [msbuild VSCode extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=msbuild&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance): they can help mainly for Visual Studio setting files completion.

The official [Microsoft vscode cpp extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) does allow to call Visual Studio `msbuild`, but only through a [Build task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), as mentioned in [issue 984](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/984).

> An answer such as "VS is much better than VSCode, so don't bother" would be a (possibly) good answer.

I doubt indeed you will find *all* the Visual Studio features directly in VSCode.